# Why does CMake syntax have redundant parentheses everywhere?

Tags: syntax, cmake, language-design

CMake's `if`s go like this:

```
if (condition)
    ...
else if (...)
    ...
else (...)
    ...
endif (...)
```

With `else if (...)` the `(...)` tests for a separate condition.
Why `else (...)` and not just `else`? Why `endif (...)` and not `endif`?

---

Cmake's functions go like this:

```
function(funcname ...)
    ...
endfunction(funcname ...)
```

Why `endfunction(funcname ...)` and not simply `endfunction`?

---

I can omit the contents of the redundant parenthesis where they appear, like so: `endif ()`. What's the purpose of this construct?

Comment: I believe it's for historical reasons. The language was not initially designed to be clean.

Comment: Talking to me? It's not me downvoted. :)

Comment: @whjm I don't mean you, but I can see someone else in the history has for some unknown reason :(

Comment: The original author(s?) were inspired by shell scripting, where everything is a command (if, then, else, for, do, end, fi, ... all of these and more are commands!). In contrast to shell scripts, they wanted parentheses, and it seems they wanted to be consistent throughout the syntax. Now they had parenthesis everywhere and didn't know what to do with them. So they allowed some arguments for `endfunction` for example. Probably with the intention of "making sure things close exactly where the programmer wanted" ... or something like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Purpose of CMake ENDIF and ELSE arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472607/purpose-of-cmake-endif-and-else-arguments)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the initial intention was that, by repeating at each clause (for example, `else` statement) the initial expression (for example, the one at the `if` statement) it would make more clear which statement was actually closed, and the parser could verify and warn nothing wrong was going on.

However, it turned out that you would have expression like:

```
if (VARIABLE matches "something")
[...] #This is executed when above condition is true
else (VARIABLE matches "something") #Looks very much like an elseif...
[...] #This is executed when above condition is false!
endif (VARIABLE matches "something")
```

Which turned out to be confusing. I am speaking about my every day experience, e.g. I write something and somebody else come to ask me "What does this does?"

So, now CMake allows also to put empty parenthesis, the above can be rewritten as:

```
if (VARIABLE matches "something")
[...] #This is executed when above condition is true
else ()
[...] #This is executed when above condition is false
endif ()
```

Which can be considered clearer. The grammar above can still be used.

To completely answer to your question, the parenthesis stay also with empty arguments because conceptually `else` and `endif` in CMake are macros like `if`, and therefore they are invoked with this grammar, a *little bit* (but not at all exactly) as functions.

---

Basically the same explanation is available in CMake FAQs: [Isn't the "Expression" in the "ELSE (Expression)" confusing?](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/FAQ#isnt-the-expression-in-the-else-expression-confusing).

To add a little bit of history, in CMake 2.4 repeating the expression was obligatory, and still in [CMake 2.6](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command:if), at least according to the documentation. The documentation was ambiguous on `else`, but adamant on `endif`:

> Note that the same expression must be given to if, and endif.

The first try to remove this constraint was introduced already with CMake 2.4.3 (year 2006), where it was possible to deactivate it by writing:

```
set(CMAKE_ALLOW_LOOSE_LOOP_CONSTRUCTS true)
```

This constraint became fully optional with [CMake 2.8](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.0/cmake.html#command:if)

> Note that the expression in the else and endif clause is optional.

Comment: Do you have a link? I'm not completely sold on this explanation. Surely someone must have realized what a dumb idea that was, and thought better of it before it made its way into the language. Perhaps there was some other reason, or maybe I've just never seen a good use case for this construct?

Comment: @sorbet I have edited the answer with some "historical" information. It was a choice, probably not a good one, and they have moved on. I don't think you should put the word "dumb" in the picture of a company that developed and gave out for free a cross compiling tool that is used successfully by many programmers.