# find*.cmake with IF(BOOLEAN) ELSE(SAME BOOLEAN AGAIN) what?

Tags: cmake

So I'm looking at FindMatio.cmake to use it for a program and keep seeing this at the bottom of everyone's version. It seems unlikely that everyone is using this incorrectly on purpose. I cannot wrap my head around why an `if else` would have the same boolean. Can anyone explain or is this just wrong?

```
IF(MATIO_FOUND)
  SET(MATIO_LIBRARIES ${MATIO_LIBRARY})
  SET(MATIO_INCLUDE_DIRS ${MATIO_INCLUDE_DIR})
ELSE(MATIO_FOUND)
  SET(MATIO_LIBRARIES)
  SET(MATIO_INCLUDE_DIRS)
ENDIF(MATIO_FOUND)
```

Comment: Most likely for readability reasons, or may be a legacy thing. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/if.html . It is completely optional and it is not evaluated at all, it is just to know (for the user) which IF it belongs to.

Comment: I see.  Good to know, I was taken aback by this, such a random thing to suddenly do!  I just can't imagine it helping anyone, but I now understand the purpose.

Comment: See also [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472607/purpose-of-cmake-endif-expression) about intention of ELSE and ENDIF parameters.